# android why this progressbar is null?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I've created a simple dialog with a progress bar the probblem is that the progress bar returning null and I wounder why

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Dialog dialog =new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.row_download);
        dialog.show();
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.row_download_progressBar1);
        TextView progressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row_download_progress);

        Log.v("", ""+progressBar);
    }
}
```

though I make its reference after the

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.row_download);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have progressbar in `row_download.xml` Change to

```
  ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)dialog. findViewById(R.id.row_download_progressBar1);
  TextView progressTextView = (TextView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.row_download_progress);
```

`findViewById` will look for a view with the id provided under the currently inflated layout. So use the dialog object to initialize your views.

Comment: gladly but SO says i cant accept before 15 min so am waitin :)

Answer (score 0):

Java code is fine. Please verify in main.xml file if you have mentioned the mandatory attributes i.e.  **android:layout_width** and **android:layout_height** for the ProgressBar component.